# Laravel: needing help querying two tables into one result

Tags: laravel

Im interested in giving users the option to add articles to custom lists that they create. (like youtube's playlist feature).

I want to know how to show a 'checked' checkbox next to a list if the article already exists within it, so they don't add it twice.

My database tables:

```
list     : | id | person_id | list_name | list_desc
list_ref : | id | list_id | article_id
```

My code for displaying lists.

```
$lists = Lists::where('person_id', Auth::user()->person_id)->get();
  @foreach($lists as $list)
    <input type="checkbox" id="available_list" value="{{ $list->id }}">
    {{ $list->list_name }}
  @endforeach
```

If anyone could help me understand the code to query the two tables to see if **list already used** || **list is available**.

Comment: Do you have a many to many relationship defined in your `Lists` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a raw expression in conjunction with a left join like this:

```
$lists = DB::table('list')->
  leftJoin('list_ref', 'list_ref.list_id', '=', 'list.id')->
  select(DB::raw('list.*, IF(list_ref.list_id = list.id, 1, 0) used'))->
  where('person_id', Auth::user()->person_id)->
  get();
```

The above uses a join to figure out which list rows has a corresponding key in the `list_ref` table. The result will contain a field called `used` that will tell if the entry has a reference in the `list_ref` table.

You should now be able to generate you form like this:

```
@foreach($lists as $list)
<input type="checkbox" id="available_list" value="{{ $list->id }}" {{ $list->used ? "CHECKED" : "" }}>
{{ $list->list_name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

First crate class, here is example for facility

```
class HotelFacilities
{
  public $facility_id;
  public $facility;
  public $status;
}
```

Get all data

```
$facilities = Facility::all();
```

Get user related data

```
$user_facilities = UserFacility::where('user_id', 3)->get();

//Here you add status 
$array_hotel_facility = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($facilities); $i++)
{        
  $obj_hotel_facilities = new HotelFacilities;
  $obj_hotel_facilities->facility_id = $facilities[$i]['id'];
  $obj_hotel_facilities->facility = $facilities[$i]['facility'];
  $obj_hotel_facilities->status = false;
  for($j=0; $j<count($user_facilities); $j++)
  {  
    if($user_facilities[$j]->facility_id ==  $facilities[$i]->id)
    {
      $obj_hotel_facilities->status = true;
    }
  }
  //Pass this array to view
  $array_hotel_facility[$i] = $obj_hotel_facilities;
}

//Pass to view
return view('extranet.view_facilities')->with('facilities', $array_hotel_facility);

//Generate UI like this        
@foreach($facilities as $facility) 
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">                                    
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" name="facilities[]" value="{{ $facility->facility_id }}" <?php if($facility->status){echo "checked";} ?>>
        {{ $facility->facility }}
      </label>                      
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```